# Display Static Block in Magento PHTML File

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm using the following code in my 2columns-right.phtml file to call  a stack block made in the Mangento admin panel onto a product page:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?> <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('recipes')->toHTML(); ?>`

I also have this code in my catalog.xml:

```
<reference name="right">
<block type="cms/block" name="recipes">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>recipes</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

Nothing is rendering on to the page. I've echoed some dummy text and that's rendered in the right spot so I know have the right .phtml file, but I am getting no sign of the block.

Comment: check your static block status is enable or not

Answer (score 0):

create `local.xml` under `app/design/frontend/your package/your template/layout/`

and out the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="cms/block" name="recipes" before="cart_sidebar"  output="toHtml">
                <!--
                    The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
                    You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
                -->
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>recipes</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

also  check cms block is `exiting or not  in admin and also check store select or not` .If multi store exit